# Make GET request inside for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

My code:

```
var locations = {"testurl1", "testurl2"}, results = [];
locations.forEach(function(location,index){
   request.get(location,function (error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
      results.add(jsonResponse.address);          
    }
   }
})

console.log(results);
```

The results are printed as blank due to asynchronous get request. How can i make this work so I have all addresses in results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe promises can help in this situation. Here is my solution:

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var Q = require('q');
var defer = Q.defer();
var promise = defer.promise;
var locations = [
  'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.instagram.com'
],
results = [];

locations.forEach(function(location, index) {
  request.get(location, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && parseInt(response.statusCode) === 200) {
       results.push(response.statusCode);
    }
    if ((locations.length - 1) === index) {
      defer.resolve();
    }
  });
});

promise.then(function() {
  console.log('RESULTS:', results);
});
```

I tested this and it's working fine. Promises are briefly explained [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki).

Answer (score 2):

After each response, check if it was the last one.

```
var locations = {"testurl1", "testurl2"}, results = [];
locations.forEach(function(location,index){
   request.get(location,function (error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
      results.add(jsonResponse.address);          

      console.log('Address received: ' + jsonResponse.address);

      if (results.length == locations.length) {
        console.log('All addresses received');
        console.log(results);
      }
    }
   }
})
```

You also may want to have some timeout, so you can show a response if it takes too long. Also, a request may fail, in which case it won't be added to result, so you can keep a separate counter to check for that. A bit rough, but something like this:

```
var locations = {"testurl1", "testurl2"}, results = [];
var failedCount = 0;
locations.forEach(function(location,index){
  request.get(location,function (error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
      results.add(jsonResponse.address);          

      console.log('Address received: ' + jsonResponse.address);
    } else {
      // Keep a counter if a request fails.
      failedCount++;
    }

    // Success + failed == total
    if (results.length + failedCount == locations.length) {
      console.log('Addresses received. ' + failedCount + ' requests have failed');
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
});

// Set a timer to check if everything is fetched in X seconds.
setTimeout(function(){
  if (results.length + failedCount < locations.length) {
    console.log('10 seconds have passed and responses are still not complete.');
  }
}, 10000);
```